# PHP comments news only one news

Tags: php, html, mysqli

Please link me any tutorial or simply inform me how to do so that it showed comments only on news which had recently been added. How I select only one?

```
<?php
                echo "<form action='".setComments($conn)."' method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='username'><br>
                    <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".date('Y-m-d H:i:s')."'><br>
                    <label>Comment:<br> <textarea cols='50' rows='6' name='message' ></textarea></label><br>
                    <button type='submit' name='commentSubmit' class='btn btn-default'>Comment</button>
                    </form>";
                getComments($conn);
                ?>

                   <div class="comment_div">
                    <?php
                    $query = "SELECT * FROM comment order by date desc";
                    mysqli_query($conn,$query) or die("Error queryng db");
                    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
                    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
                        $name = $row['name'];
                        $com = $row['comment'];
                        $date = $row['date'];
                        echo "
                            <div class='commentinfo'>
                            <p class='username'>სახელი: $name ; თარიღი: $date</p>
                            <p class='comment'>კომენტარი: <br> $com</p>
                            </div>
                            ";
                    }
                    ?>
```

in comments.php :

```
<?php
function setComments($conn) {
    if (isset($_POST['commentSubmit'])) {
        $uid = $_POST['username'];
        $date = $_POST['date'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $sql = "INSERT INTO comments (username,date,message) VALUES ('$uid','$date', '$message')";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    }
}

function getComments ($conn) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['username']."<br>";
        echo $row['date']."<br>";
        echo $row['message']."<br><br>";
    };
    echo "
        <form method='post' action'editcomment.php'>
            <input type='hidden' name='id' value='".$row['id']."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='username' value='".$row['username']."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='date' value='".$row['date']."'>
            <input type='hidden' name='message' value='".$row['message']."'>
            <button>შესწორება</button>
    ";

}
```

I want to show only news posted comment an I have to all news comments other news.

Comment: you want to get only last comment entered after submit button is pressed right??

Comment: no, i want to where i added something news and someone make comment show only this news comment not all other comment. sorry for my bad english

Comment: Note, you are vulnerable to SQL Injections right now. You need to start using prepared statements

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `LIMIT` and `ORDER BY` tags in your query, so it would look something like this:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";
```

This query has two new parameters, we need to order it by ID so we can get the descending (that's what `DESC` is used for) and we limit the number to 1; if you need more you can change the number.

If you have a specific item you want to pull you can use `WHERE` clause in your query: `WHERE id = #call for id#`

---

To make sure the comment only comes up in the article you need to create some sort of identifier row for your comments and compare it in your posts:

```
// get the post ID from the database
$post_id = $row['id'];

// now that you have the post id, and assuming you have an identifier add the WHERE clause
$sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_post_id = " . $post_id;
```

To add the `comment_post_id` add that when they enter the comment, from the the current post they are in.

So if you are post `id` is 12, the comments made in the that post should have their `comment_post_id` equals to 12.

Comment: maybe i have wrong in mysql relationships dont have and its necessary?

Comment: What are you asking? I am sorry I don't understand

Comment: i think i have a mistake in mysql, there's no relationship between news id and comments id and is it needed ? To be more certain, when i add one article e.g. and somebody leaves a comment, i want that comment to stick to that article only and does not apply to other articles.

Comment: @levanrostoshvili I updated my answer, hope it helps

Comment: The `comment_post_id` is the relationship; that's how you determine to pull the comment or not. `if (comment_post_id == post_id) { show comment }`

Comment: @levanrostoshvili does that make sense, mate?

Comment: try evrything but dont work :S my mistake. if you are not buys an have time can you show me ?

Comment: @levanrostoshvili let me know how I can help, where are you having an issue?

Comment: where i can upload ?

Comment: full projet it is just for me and i have not proble for see you

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I'll look though the project and let you know man... We should move to the chat, shouldn't really be having a conversation in the comments

Comment: i  dont know this site rules sorry

Comment: can  you help me ?

Comment: Meet me in the chat @levanrostoshvili

Comment: where? i can chat with you?

Comment: Actually; explain to me what the problem you are having here... I don't know if you would have access to the chat yet. Try to explain exactly where the problem is.

Comment: When I add some news and somebody writes a comment, I want that comment to appear only on that certain news not on other news as well

Comment: I am looking through your code right now, which file is the one where the user will see the post and comment? I am having a bit of trouble since the file is in a different language

Comment: check fullstory section this is where i have code for comments

Comment: hello. did you se?

Answer (score 0):

Your select query is missing where clause. It should look like.

```
$sql ="select  * from comments where news_id='".$news_id."';
```

Comment: maybe i have wrong in mysql relationships dont have and its necessary?

Comment: Yes. If you want to get comments of that particular news only than your comments table must have news_id field.